# iOS SKProduct How to retrieve free trial information of IAP ?

Tags: ios, subscription, skproduct, auto-renewable

I'm developing an iOS app that will include auto renewable subscriptions. 
I want to dynamically populate an upgrade screen based on the available list of subscriptions. While I can easily pull the price information, title and description I can't seem to successfully pull the free trial information.

Is there any way to retrieve a product's free trial information?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, it's not possible without your own custom solution. See: [StoreKit on iOS - autorenewable subscription - How to know whether it is a free trial or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16912969/storekit-on-ios-autorenewable-subscription-how-to-know-whether-it-is-a-free)